# React Animations - change only one logo at a time from a list of 6 initial logos displayed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a feature where I need to change only one logo at a time out of a list of 6 logos displayed initally.

The example is shown here:: https://www.loom.com/share/6a282423368a46418248a789ce4fc139

And its there in this website also in the bottom:: https://www.wonderlandams.com/about?fbclid=IwAR0wfFrqYVwor1UJfZGcWK2MaU0kBWNiaacg8kGb_IC--VaziorY6BDt7lA.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import tw from 'twin.macro'
import Image from './image'

const LogoGrid = ({ logos, style }) => {
  const groupDisplay = logos.slice(0, 6);
  const [group, setGroup] = useState(groupDisplay);
  const [groupLength, setGroupLength] = useState(0);
  let shuffledLogos, i;


  const shuffle = (array) => array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("UEFFECT RUNNING");
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
      shuffledLogos = shuffle(logos);
      let gl = groupLength + 1 ;
   
      if(groupDisplay[i] == logos[i]) {
        let k = i + 1;
        groupDisplay[i] = shuffledLogos[k];
      }
      else {
        groupDisplay[i] = shuffledLogos[i];
      }
      setGroupLength(gl)
      setGroup(groupDisplay)
      
    }, 2000)
    return () => clearInterval(timer)
  }, [group, groupLength])

  return (
    <div css={[tw`relative`, style]}>
      <div
        css={[
          tw`opacity-0 grid-cols-3 grid-rows-2 gap-12
          lg:(gap-x-16 gap-y-12 mt-26) xl:gap-x-32`,
          tw`grid transition transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in-out opacity-100`,
        ]}
      >
        {(group || []).map((logo, index) => (
          <div key={index} css={tw`h-12`}>
            <Image image={logo} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default LogoGrid
```

I have made one component using tailwind css but it does not work as expected. Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction or any changes in the logic that can give me similar effects ?